# Creating a sticky reactive value (Subject)

Tags: typescript, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I intend to create a reactive "value" of generic type `T` with following properties:

1. It can be used as observable by multiple subscribers.
2. The first subscriber triggers a value calculation.
3. Any new subscriber is dispatched the last cached value.
4. A new value can be externally set anytime and is published to all subscribers.
5. When last subscriber is removed, any ongoing calculation must stop.
6. When a new value is set externally, any triggered calculation result is ignored.

Intended usage:

```
// calculates value on demand
function getValue<Number>():Observable<Number>{
  // return an observable of some number, takes 1-2 seconds to calculate
}

// sticky observable of value
const value = new StickyValue<Number>(getValue);

// first subscriber triggers calculation
value.subscribe((n) => console.log(n));

// value can be set externally, the subscribers get this value ignoring any triggered calculation result
value.next(500);

// second subscriber gets value that was last set or last calculated
value.subscribe((n) => console.log(n));
```

Assumptions: `calculation()` is a simple function that returns Observable of the value

From comments, I find that `BehaviourSubject` comes close. But it still doesn't satisfy the conditions 2 and 6.

Comment: There is the [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) in rxjs that does this.

Comment: @Tao See updated question.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you intend to achieve, but I think you coud try subclassing BehaviorSubject and overriding the `next` and `subscribe` methods.